# Extension Python by C++: How to determine python function name on C callback

Tags: python, c++, c, embedding

I have extension of Python by C++ with [Python API](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).
There is one c function handler for different python functions. 
How in the c function handler I can determine a python function  which called me?
Handler argument PyObject* self is null...

I have a Methods table

```
<...>
PyObject* pyCallBackFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kw){
// how i can determine here what python function called me?
// self = 0x00 on callback...
}
<...>
std::vector<char*> pyFuncs;
pyFuncs.push_back("Main");
pyFuncs.push_back("testMethod");
pyFuncs.push_back("func3");
this->PyMethodDefTable = (PyMethodDef*) malloc(sizeof(PyMethodDef)*(pyFuncs.size()+1));
for (unsigned int i=0; i<pyFuncs.size();++i){
  this->PyMethodDefTable[i] = (PyMethodDef) {pyFuncs[i],pyCallBackFunction,METH_KEYWORDS,pyFuncs[i]};}
PyMethodDef nullDef = (PyMethodDef){NULL, NULL, 0, NULL};
this->PyMethodDefTable[pyFuncs.size()] = nullDef ;
<...>
PyObject *m = Py_InitModule("testModule", this->methodsTable);
```

Python call:

```
import testModule
def Main():
  res1 = testModule.testMethod(arg1="test string", arg2= 34)
  res2 = testModule.func3(arg1="test string2", arg2= 434)
  return 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just have `testMethod()` and `func3()` be a small function that calls the common code with an extra argument?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `PyEval_GetFrame()` which gives you the pointer to the current frame object `PyFrameObject` This object has a member named `f_code` which is a `PyCodeObject` and this code object has a member called `co_name` which is a `PyObject` which is actually a string, from which you can extract the name of the function you are in.

From python itself this can be accessed with `sys._getframe(0).f_code.co_name`

Comment: thanks for your comment! is this method is thread safe? it's seems like a hack...

Comment: Nothing it CPython is thread safe. Everything you do with the interpreter needs to be done with the GIL locked using `PyGILState_Ensure()` and `PyGILState_Release()`

Comment: I have coded your solution, but it return not the name of called function, but the name of high-level function. (in my case it return "Main") solution:  PyFrameObject* backTrace = PyEval_GetFrame();
    PyCodeObject* code = ((_frame*)backTrace)->f_code;
    PyObject* funcName = code->co_name;
    char* strFuncName =  PyString_AS_STRING(funcName);